# how to get raw bytes from querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, encoding

is there possibility to get raw bytes from querystring?

I have there windows-1250 and url encoded bytes and Request.QueryString["xx"] is string (internally encoded in utf-16)

I need bytes to be able to convert it from windows-1250 to utf-8

Sample for LINQpad follows:

```
void Main()
{
    var txt="p%E1lava"; // this and next line simulates Request.QueryString["txt"]
    txt = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(txt);
    Console.WriteLine(txt);
    Encoding wind1250 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250);
    Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;  
    byte[] wind1250Bytes = wind1250.GetBytes(txt); // here is problem, bytes are internally utf-16
    byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(wind1250, utf8, wind1250Bytes);
    string utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
    Console.WriteLine(utf8String);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, need to use UrlDecode (with encoding specified) on Request.Url.Query:

```
var wind1250 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250);


var querystring = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Url.Query, wind1250);//;    
var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);
Response.Write(qs["Where"]);
```